# How can I stop matlab pde solver in pde tool box when solution is unstable

Tags: matlab, pde

I am solving two coupled time dependent PDE eqations using pde tool box.The simulation box size is x=6 and y=10.Currently I solve it properly and acces the solution data using 
results = solvepde(model,tlist); u = results.NodalSolution(:,1,:);

What I need to do is now to stop the code when the solution u is unstable along the y axis.That means I want to monitor solution of u along y axis while running the code and stop it when it meets a criteria that I want.(For example I want to stop the code when solution of u along y equals to 0)..How can I do it using pde tool box?

Here is what I tried so far.Is there easy way to access the results while code is running?.That is I want to access the solution for each time step.

```
 %calculate solutions
  n=4000;
  tlist = linspace(0,200,n);
  partial=zeros(49,1);

  for i=1:n
       results = solvepde(model,tlist(i:i+1));
       u = results.NodalSolution(:,1,1);
       v=results.NodalSolution(:,2,1);
       u1=results.NodalSolution(113:161,1,1);
       u2=results.NodalSolution(1,1,1);
       u3=results.NodalSolution(4,1,1);
      for j=1:49
          partial(j)=u1(j)-0.5*u2-0.5*u3;
      end
      sigma=sum(partial);
      if sigma>1e-4
          disp('verified')
          return
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to stop a code during execution:

- `keyboard`

Using this function stops the execution and gives you access to the keyboard, such that you can see all values.

- `warning('Solution is unstable')`

This won't actually stop the code but will give you a warning stating that the solution is unstable.

- `error('Solution is unstable')`

This will actually stop the code, giving you the error, that the solution is unstable.

- `break`

This will not give you any feedback, but it will stop the for-loop and then continue the rest of the code.

In all cases you include the way of stopping the code in an if-statement, like

```
if (all(u==0))
    *statement from above*
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now code has ability to stop. But code is very slow since it calculate same results twise as you can see (tlist(i:i+1). So  what I need to know is that,is there way to access the results while it execute the pdesolve function.If there is way I can drop all the for function. Currently results.NodalSolution give access to results after pdesolve compute all the solution. That is I can only see the result after it reaches to 200s.